# Computer saying Limited Connection and all other PCs working

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wired-networking

My PC says "Limited Internet Access" every time I try to connect to the internet. All the other PCs on my network work fine, so it is not an issue with my router or ISP, and I have tried multiple NICs, both wired and wireless, all with the same result. Here is a picture of my Network and Sharing Center Network Map in Control Panel:
[Picture of Network & Sharing Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtJd6.png)

[Also here is my IPCONFIG -all](http://pastebin.com/eTtZqzZE)

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Does it work with an Ethernet connection? Just off the top of my head, I would try to fully reset the wireless drivers. Turn off the WIFI, Go to Device manager, Find the WIFI driver and uninstall. Reboot. Turn on the WIFI and let windows reinstall the driver. Also how many local area connections do you have?

Comment: Also in your first picture, in Network and sharing settings can you click on Change adapter settings and post a screenshot of that page.

Comment: No it does not work on and Ethernet connection. Which adapter do you want to see? I have 2 RJ-45 Ethernet jacks and 1 WiFi card. And I have tried to reset the drivers with no avail. And all of the connections say Limited.

Comment: That's odd that Ethernet doesn't work at all. How old is the windows build on the machine, I am assuming it is a desktop? Is it fully updated? And did this just start happening on that PC, or has it done it since windows was installed? Are the RJ-45 jacks both on a different card, or is one of them internal to the motherboard? Also can you connect to the router page, and if so what method WIFI or Ethernet?

Comment: Yes it is a desktop. This all started happening after I received Windows Updates. It worked before I shut it down and it updated. The next day I discovered this issue when I booted it up and tried to get on the Internet. Both RJ45 jacks are on the motherboard. I cannot connect to the router admin page either method.

Comment: Thanks for that, Considering it was after an update Give this a try. Go to Control panel, Click on Programs and Features. On the left click on View installed Updates. And Click on the most recent one and click Uninstall Make a note of the name of the update and write it down. If it shows something about a Driver, It probably installed an updated Driver that didn't work well. When windows Reboots Go to updates and change the settings to manually install updates. Check updates. If you see the noted update click on Hide and then you can change the settings to auto again. Let me know if this works

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try to do a system restore if you have a recent restore point to work with. Start, Type restore click enter. Click next and select a point that was before the update.

Comment: There were no driver updates. All the updates had to do with MS Office. I had no restore point before the update. I am running an avast! antivirus boot time scan so maybe if it is a virus that will fix it. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can go ahead and uninstall the last MS update It won't hurt anything. If the internet works then we know it was limited to that specific update.

Comment: Ok will do as soon as the boot-time scan is done running.

Comment: If there are multiple updates that installed on the day it quit working, I would try to uninstall them one at a time and see which one works. I don't think Microsoft lets you uninstall multiple updates, so you might have to do them one at a time. Also take out the wifi card and any extra Ethernet cards you have and just work with one Ethernet port. Then you can add the other back after the Ethernet works.

Comment: Sorry but one last thing to mention. Do you have a modem and then a router. if so, Try plugging the problem machine directly into the modem via Ethernet and see if that does anything. You don't have a Default Gateway defined in your settings, Considering it worked before It might still be linked to a bad update, but I would try bypassing the router just for the simplicity of troubleshooting. Make sure to set the settings in adapter settings back to automatically obtain IP and DNS as was tried in your previous post to the same problem. I will be unable to provide much help until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue by doing a clean install of Windows 7. Such a pain to do, and I believe the whole problem was caused by a bad Windows Update